# Some Serious looking bug in instnaceof or App package

Tags: java, android, android-intent, instanceof

I made 2 activities and an Intent extended class named SomeSpecialIntent, when you press on the first activity's textview you go to the second using new SomeSpecialIntent class instnace, but something strange goes with it on the way, because the phrase getIntent() instnaceof SomeSpecialIntent returns false on the second activity!

whats up with that?

the code for the check i made:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        textView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new SomeSpecialIntent(MainActivity.this,SomeActivity.class));
            }

        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }


}


public class SomeActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Log.d("Check",""+(getIntent() instanceof SomeSpecialIntent));//returns false!!!!
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}


public class SomeSpecialIntent extends Intent {

    public SomeSpecialIntent(Context context,
            Class<?> class1) {
        super(context,class1);
    }

}
```

Comment: not a bug ... afaik intents are serilized and recreated

Comment: well if it makes them lose their identity then it is a bad thing, is it not? anyway, does that mean that i cant extend Intent and make it work?

Comment: i think you can't ... all you can do is make some wraper class but its only purpose should be easier setting getting extras ... why they work like that .. well, in most cases intents are passed between different processes so they cant be passed by instance ... you can also try to pas your special class IN intent but it should implement parcelable

Comment: ehhh intents are such trouble... there goes polymorphism + encapsulation

Comment: Intents aren't intended to be extended. They are just a "transport mechanism". Why would you want to extend it? You can attach anything you want to an Intent by using the "extras".